# Green's Theorem Bounded by Triangle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Use greens theorem to evaluate

$$I= \oint_R(12x^2 - 32y^2) \, dx + (16y-24xy) \, dy $$

where $R$ is the triangle bounded by $y = 0$, $x = 0$, and $x+y = 4$

Comment: You didn't say please.

Comment: Please can you help me get the integral :)

Comment: There are several Green's theorems. Some specification which one is expected to be used would help.

Comment: @SalaChotaKutta : Usually it is expected that you would give some of your thoughts on your unsuccessful attempts to answer the question.  That may be the reason why someone down-voted it.

Answer (score 3):

Green's theorem:

$$\oint_RP(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=\iint_D(Q_x(x,y)-P_y(x,y))dA$$

Where $D$ is the region enclosed by $R$.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(16y-24xy)=-24y$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(12x^2-32y^2)=-64y$$

Using Fubini's theorem this is both a type 1 and a type 2 region.

**Type 1**:
$$\begin{align}
0 &< x < (-y+4) \\
0 &< y < 4
\end{align}$$
$$I=\int_0^4\int_0^{-y+4}40y\space{dx}\space{dy}$$

Or **type 2**:
$$\begin{align}
0 &< y < (-x+4) \\
0 &< x < 4
\end{align}$$
$$I=\int_0^4\int_0^{-x+4}40y\space{dy}\space{dx}$$

Comment: what would your integral be over?

Comment: I think you need to subtract the 24 from the 64, not add (the orientation changes when the order of integration is changed).

Comment: @robjohn Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: @ZettaSuro can we chat about this?

Comment: @jainsmit sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9627/discussion-between-zettasuro-and-jain-smit)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt they're expected to do a change of variables. But, rather than setting up the standard double integral, a more conceptual approach is to think about this in terms of center of mass. Recall that the $x$-coordinate and $y$-coordinate of the center of mass are given by
$$\bar x = \frac{\iint_R x\,dA}{\text{area}(R)} \quad \bar y = \frac{\iint_R y\,dA}{\text{area}(R)}\,.$$
For other sorts of regions, the center of mass may be geometrically obvious. For a triangle, you may recall that the center of mass is at the point $2/3$ the way down each of the medians. For this triangle, then, it will be at $(\bar x,\bar y) = (4/3,/4/3)$, and you can easily solve for the double integral by knowing this and $\text{area}(R)$.